# Conversion from string to type Double is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a value to a field that has value from before.
My code is:

```
Dim Credits As Integer = Int64.Parse(FinalPay.ToString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Update Users Set Credit=Credit+" + Credits + 
                          " Where Email ='" + UserEmail + "'", con)
```

But I get an error that says:

> "Conversion from string to double is not valid"

Comment: `Dim Credits As Integer = Int64.Parse(FinalPay.ToString)` will not compile if `Option Strict` set to `On`. And will throw exception at runtime if value of `FinalPay` exceeds maximum value of Integer(Int32) type

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Dim Credits As Integer = Int64.Parse(FinalPay.ToString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Update Users Set Credit=Credit+" & Credits & 
                                                " Where Email ='" & UserEmail & "'", con)
```

When you want to concat a string in vb you want to use the "&" operator

Comment: you are creating the sql command using strings.Lets say credits = 100 the request will look like :  Update Users Set Credit=Credit+100 Where Email ="mail@mail.com"

Comment: @sapi That won't work with Option Strict On, which should always be used. (Except for some exceptional circumstances, which this is not.)

Comment: Please do not encourage people to use string concatenation for creating sql queries. Using `SqlParameter` will eliminate OP's problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you use SQL parameters it should work correctly:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Users SET Credit = Credit + @Credits Where Email = @Email", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Credits", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = finalPay})
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Email", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Size = 256, .Value = userEmail})
```

Adjust each parameter type (and size) to match the declarations in the database.